# Persistence.xml overridden in Arquillian tests

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, integration-testing, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

Arquillian examples mainly show how to construct WarArchive, JavaArchive, etc. I can't find any good example how to override one of jar files which exists in already compile war file.

The reason is that one of the jars contains persistence.xml which I wan't to override to defined for instance hbm2ddl.auto etc.

What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: I don't think that you can change pre-compiled jars of your war. For this purpose you will have to replace the jar by a test version of this jar for arquillian tests. How is your setup (project structure, packaging, pom, ...)?

Comment: My flow is that i create war file, then I make just ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(WebArchive, new File("target/myArchive.war") so my persistence xml is already there. I've seen somewhere an example how to override persistence.xml with new classloader but I can't find it

Comment: The example might be including a test persistence.xml in src/test/resources and packaging this one with ShrinkWrap since this file is on classpath for test classes instead of the one from src/main/resources. But in your case with the pre-built WAR, I'm not sure if there's a way you can achieve what you want.

Comment: I agree with @shi; in this scenario with had to make the persistence.xml scope independet, maybe using jndi datasource name, then you can use your testing embedded application server with that jndi datasource configured for test purpose

Comment: I have my persistence unit defined using jndi. The only problem I have is when I want to use in memory database like h2, I would like to call hbm2ddl to create in mermory tables based on my entities. That is why I would need to override persistence.xml. Of course there are possiblities like create schema direct from sql file, but I would like to generate my schema directly from entities. But it seems this case is not well supported by the framework :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be that your using `ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile`. From my experience with Arquillian it better to create a custom WAR/JAR for each test. The method which creates the deployment usually looks like this:

```java
@Deployment
public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    //Load dependencies from POM
    final PomEquippedResolveStage pom = Maven
        .resolver()
        .loadPomFromFile("pom.xml");
    final PomEquippedResolveStage dependencies = pom
        .importCompileAndRuntimeDependencies();
    final File[] libs =         
      dependencies.resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();

    return ShrinkWrap
      .create(WebArchive.class,
              "ExampleArchive.war")
      .addPackage(org.example.Example.class.getPackage())
      .addAsLibraries(files)
      .addAsResource("test-persistence.xml",
                    "META-INF/persistence.xml")
      .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "WEB-INF/beans.xml"); 

}
```

The `test-persistence.xml` goes into your test resources directory.

Comment: But the questions says about replacing the persistence of an existing jar, which propably is used as a depedency to the actuall integration test. What you show here is to set a persistence file for the war created. The included dependencies will still point to their own persistence file which they are already compiled with.